# What does "on top of something" mean in the following sentanes?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, idioms

I saw some sentences using "on top of" while I was reading some book which was about ASP.NET Core (which is a Microsoft Web Development Framework).
the sentences:

> 1-(MVC) It was created **on top of** the components for Web Forms.

> 2- Dot Net Core is built **on top of** the new dot net core framework.

I have searched for some definitions for "on top of something" and also for knowing that how to use this idiom in a sentence, but actually haven't realized what "on top of" mean here in these two sentences!
So would anybody explain it to me please?

Comment: *For this usage*, simply regard it as synonymous with "[on](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on)." Specifically, "positioned physically above and contacting ___": "The house is built on top of the foundation." Obviously, for .Net, it's used metaphorically: it's not literally positioned "on top of" a framework—but then it's not literally "built" either.

Comment: Also, it's not really an idiom, just an idiomatic usage—I thought you were going to ask about the idiom "on top of it" which means in control of a situation.

Comment: @AndyBonner can we say that the Earth was built on top of the water and land, according to your explanation?

Comment: Sorry, your comment makes sense in response to Casey's answer, but not to my explanation. I left a comment rather than an answer because these are not unusual usages, but common dictionary definitions. Please edit your question to show that you have looked up "built," "on," and "top," and how those entries fail to answer your questions. "On top of X" does *not* mean "using X." It means "on." If it helps, add "the": "on the top of." The earth is not "on top of" anything, unless perhaps it is four elephants and the great turtle A'Tuin.

Comment: Yes, I exactly know what you mean, but I just wanted you to help me know if I can use "on top of" in my response to **Casey**. I mean I just wanted to know whether to use "on top of" instead of "using" in that example I asked from **Casey** or not?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm confused—it sounds like you understand the use of "on top of" and are trying to prove Casey wrong by showing a use for which their definition would clearly not make sense? If so, that's not very productive. If not, *please edit* your question to show the research you've already done and what questions you still have afterward.

Answer (score 2):

This means that it was built using those other tools. The metaphor here is a physical building, which is built on top of some sort of foundation.

Comment: I think this is a good answer. So can we say that the Earth was built on top of the water and land, according to your explanation?

Comment: Thanks for contributing! However, the continuing confusion (or is it trolling?) shows why it's good to wait for a question to meet our requirements before giving an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Thanks. So would you give me an example for where to use "on top of" in a sentence, please?

Comment: @AndyBonner I've been on Stack Exchange for the better part of the decade and I honestly still don't really get what people want.  Just a few weeks ago I was hearing moderators say comments were absolutely the wrong place for answers and never write one there.

Comment: @HosseinDara No, that doesn't fit the metaphor.  The water and dirt are components of the planet, not a foundation for them.

Comment: In fairness, the very first thing I did on this question was add a comment that really should have been an answer—my bad. My point was, we have "this meaning can be easily found in a dictionary" as a close-reason, and the OP seems confused by what is not an edge case but the common meanings of common words. Technically, we're waiting for them to show that the dictionary entries are insufficient. @HosseinDara I'm going to go ahead and vote to close. Please edit to show that you've checked a dictionary and what confuses you afterward, and it can be reopened.